# Windows Mobile: how do I know if I have a GPS installed?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, gps

I'm developing a Windows Mobile 5.0 and above application with C#, .NET Compact Framework 2.0 SP2.
How do I know if I have a GPS installed? Is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [GPS.net](http://gps3.codeplex.com/) for developing GPS related applications and this framework has an option to detect GPS devices.